# HMM - Matlab for data set to detect anomaly

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, markov-process

I have a dataset of oil temperatures. The time series consist of 100 hours of measurement at every second. There is an anomaly in the data that I would like to detect using Hidden Markov Models (HMM). In Matlab I used `hmmgenerate`, however I'm not able to link my data to the assumed probabilities. Instead random states and sequences are generated. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Matlab HMM, but from looking at the documentation, perhaps hmmtrain would better suit your objective? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hmmtrain.html

Comment: Welcome to DataScience SE. If you can post some code and some output it would be helpful for people.